# CLEAN URL - Include the Drupal-specific settings directly into .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, clean-urls

I read the [Configure clean URL](https://www.drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls#enabling-6)

It ask to add the code below into .htaccess file.

```
<Directory /var/www/example.com>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</Directory>
```

/var/www/drupal is the directory where I copied all the Drupal files.

So the final code should I add into it is

```
<Directory /var/www/drupal>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</Directory>
```

Is that right?

Comment: Is that a question ? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says to use that in the configuration file. You can not use `<Directory>` directive inside `.htaccess`. The very nature of `.htaccess` is already per directory context. Remove the directive and only use the rewriterules. This is only for Drupal **6**

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Drupal **7 or 8**

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Try to understand what the instructions have and you need to use the appropriate one for your install. The link you provide is pretty detailed info.

Comment: I have tried remove <Directory> directive inside .htaccess. But it still can't enabled the CLEAN URL. Do I need to restart apache after make the changes?

Comment: If you had <Directory> inside .htaccess file and you did **not** get a **500 internal error** then your .htaccess file not being read and is not enabled. You need to add `AllowOverride All` in your Apache config/virtual host file and restart Apache.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just found AllowOverride None is in another file. Can you help me take a look for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31064092/change-allowoverride-none-to-allowoverride-all