# Change AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All

Tags: apache, .htaccess

These two file have the same code inside.

> **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default**
>
> **/etc/apache2/sites-available/default**

I would like to change ***AllowOverride None*** to **AllowOverride All**.
Which file should I change？

Is all the ***AllowOverride None*** change to ***AllowOverride All***?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/drupal
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/drupal>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

> /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
>
> /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

Actually these are not **2** files. One is a [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) of the other. So that is why they are exactly the same.

The sites-**available** just shows which sites you have on your system. But sites-**enabled** show which one's are in use.

So just change the original in `sites-available` because they are the same file. And yes use `AllowOverride All` to enable .htaccess use under `<Directory /var/www/drupal>` block.

You can use commands `a2ensite` and `a2dissite` to enable and disable sites if you add more later. The link below gives exact instructions if you ever need to do that, which you shouldn't since your site is live.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/a2ensite.8.html